# Python Dataframe: String in DF Column Contains Substring from Different DF and Substring Values Returned When Match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, isin

Colleagues,

Maybe you can help me with what appears to be simple task, but I am not yet experianced enough to figure it out.

Lets say we have two dataframes:

1. df1 contains substrings;
2. df2 contains longer blocks of text, some of them contain substrings from df1.

```
df1 = {'subst': ['LONDON BRIDGE', 'TRUE GRIT', 'FIVE TIMES FIVE', 'THREE TIME DEAD', 'TRUE IS NOT', 'OH NO', 'LEBRON JAMES']}

df2 = {'strng': ['LEBRON JAMES SCORED 20', 'THREE TIMES DEAD JOHNY WAS HELL OF THE COOK', 'TRUE IS NOT WHAT YOU THINK', 'FIVE TIMES FIVE IS NOT WHAT LEBRON SCORED']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Here is what I need:

1. I need to iterate through the rows to check if substrings in df1['subst'] are present anywhere in df2['strng']
2. If it is present in df2, I want new column ['match_df1'] in df2 that would contain substring value from df1.

Final output in df2 would look something like this

| strng | match_df1 |
| --- | --- |
| LEBRON JAMES SCORED 20 | LEBRON JAMES |
| THREE TIMES DEAD JOHNY WAS HELL OF THE COOK | THREE TIMES DEAD |
| TRUE IS NOT WHAT YOU THINK | TRUE IS NOT |
| FIVE TIMES FIVE IS NOT WHAT LEBRON SCORED | FIVE TIMES FIVE |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching substring of a dataframe if it exists in another dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240696/searching-substring-of-a-dataframe-if-it-exists-in-another-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @Chris, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64240696/searching-substring-of-a-dataframe-if-it-exists-in-another-dataframe-column) might do the job.
Then just filter on the empty string like so :

```py
>>> for ind1 in df1.index:
...    df1.loc[ind1, 'strng'] = ', '.join(list(df2[df2['strng'].str.contains(df1['subst'][ind1])]['strng']))
>>> df1[df1['strng'].str.len() > 0]
    subst                strng
2   FIVE TIMES FIVE      FIVE TIMES FIVE IS NOT WHAT LEBRON SCORED
4   TRUE IS NOT          TRUE IS NOT WHAT YOU THINK
6   LEBRON JAMES         LEBRON JAMES SCORED 20
```

All code :

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = {'subst': ['LONDON BRIDGE', 'TRUE GRIT', 'FIVE TIMES FIVE', 'THREE TIME DEAD', 'TRUE IS NOT', 'OH NO', 'LEBRON JAMES']}
df2 = {'strng': ['LEBRON JAMES SCORED 20', 'THREE TIMES DEAD JOHNY WAS HELL OF THE COOK', 'TRUE IS NOT WHAT YOU THINK', 'FIVE TIMES FIVE IS NOT WHAT LEBRON SCORED']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

for ind1 in df1.index:
   df1.loc[ind1, 'strng'] = ', '.join(list(df2[df2['strng'].str.contains(df1['subst'][ind1])]['strng']))
df1[df1['strng'].str.len() > 0]
```

Comment: Thank a lot! Though when trying to execute this on my data (as well as example), I am getting "'list' object is not callable" error.

Comment: Hi @Raganosis, I just rerun your 4 lines of code followed by mine and I get the same exact result without any error on my side. I added the exact code I just run at the end of the answer, can you copy and try it on your side to see if you still have an error ?

Comment: Hi @tlentali, thanks again. Interestingly works only when I restarted python. Anyway, thanks a lot, it solves the issue!